# Unknown component identification (SMD Marking L43)

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

[image]

What is this component? I need to replace it. How to get replacement.?

Answer (score 6):

From the code (and silkscreen)  looks like a BAT54C, common cathode, dual diode. Several possible manufacturers, but here's a link to the [Vishay datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/en/product/85508/).

The date and lotcodes also fit with specific SOT23 marking pattern in the general Vishay [diode marking datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf).

A photo (sadly with poor contrast) of the Vishay partv from the Newark website shown below [image]

And a better photo from icsc [here.](https://assets.lcsc.com/images/lcsc/900x900/20230125_Vishay-Intertech-BAT54C-E3-08_C5224087_front.jpg) (link provided by nanash1 in the comments).

[image]

Comment: lcsc has a [better photo](https://assets.lcsc.com/images/lcsc/900x900/20230125_Vishay-Intertech-BAT54C-E3-08_C5224087_front.jpg) of the Vishay markings.